# How can one let the emulator in Android Studio work faster?

Tags: android, hosts, android-studio, emulator

I am trying to build a simple app in Android Studio. Unfortunately every time when I am trying to run it I get the message "System UI isn't responding" and the emulator works really slowly.

I've read this about this problem:

"The emulator tends to function extremely slowly if you are compiling aosp for a different architecture than your host machine. If you are building on an x86 machine an x86 build will result in a significantly faster emulator that won't eat up all of your machine's resources."

But I don't understand it since I am an absolute beginner (in programming and IT stuff). So what is a host machine? How can I know/Where have I to search to know on what a machine I am building? (e.g. x86 machine) and how can I know the same for my build?

Thank you very much for every answer.

Katharina Hohenfels

And I am sorry if I couldn't ask the question in a way you can understand my problem. Because I really don't know much about IT, I have also problems to describe my problem in a way you can understand me or you have all information. So please if there is missing information, tell me.

By the way it would be also nice if somebody has some links to websites for beginners to learn some IT words, then I maybe would understand more...

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up

The physical computer is your host machine.  You have an x86 system, virtually all home computers are x86 now.  x86 is the nomenclature used to describe Intel based computers that run Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

To speed up Android Studio, you'd need faster hardware, i.e. a faster CPU, possibly more RAM, or an SSD instead of a hard drive.

Emulation is the process that allows one CPU architecture to run software built for another architecture, in your case x86 running ARM software. 
Emulation:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator
Also, virtual machines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine 
Review the Android Studio docs here:  https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/

If you find something you don't understand, do a web search, Google, Bing, etc, or you can search on Wikipedia.

Basic education is beyond the scope of this forum.